# Flexslider carousel show two images when width is 768px

Tags: flexslider

**Problem**
I use the flexslider carousel to a number of images to show. What I want now is, when the browser has a certain width drop a break, which for example is incidental to 768px 2 images are shown. Currently you see an image at a certain width but half and wants to these points with javascript / jquery to give many pictures there must fully show.

So my question is, how I can make an if statement for when the browser width is for example 768px width, is must show two images...

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: true,
    itemWidth: 320,
    itemMargin: 0,
    minItems: 2,
    maxItems: 5,
    start: function(slider){
        $('body').removeClass('loading');
    }
});
```

Check code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7dTx/15/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if statement for widths like this:

```
if ($(window).width() < 960) {
   alert('Less than 960');
}
else {
   alert('More than 960');
}
```

... and to contain that, you might like to combine your document ready function with a window resize function.

```
$(document).ready(myfunction);
$(window).resize(myfunction);

function myfunction() {
    // Pace the if/else here, do whatever
}
```

In terms of showing two images it think you should be able to be achieve that by setting slide widths and offsets in the flexslider function - or with css. here are the options i'm talking about:

```
itemWidth: 490, // or whatever is 1/2 of your width
itemMargin: 30, // experiment here!
minItems: 1, // or 2
```

Here's an edited version of your JS fiddle demo! http://jsfiddle.net/tM2a8/